# OpenGL: object order in zbuffer (LWJGL 3 and GLFW 3)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm back with "traditional" depth test problem; I've tried many things, googled ungooglable, but still didn't find solution.

I render some objects using Java and LWJGL 3 (with GLFW), cubes are rendered with z-buffer enabled (I think):

```
// renderer setup
@Override
public void setup() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // cull face? Maybe? .... dunno
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    // here, hey, OpenGL, do you see this thing!?
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(true);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glDisable(GL_DITHER);
}
```

But if I render cubes (using VBOs), they overdraw each other.

```
// window creation
    if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        throw new DeRiveanException("Cannot init GLWF subsystem.");
    }
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    long monitorHandle = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    ByteBuffer videModeBuffer = glfwGetVideoMode(monitorHandle);
    setWidth(GLFWvidmode.width(videModeBuffer) * 3 / 4);
    setHeight(GLFWvidmode.height(videModeBuffer) * 3 / 4);
    if((windowHandle = glfwCreateWindow(getWidth(), getHeight(), "title goes here", 0, 0)) == 0) {
        throw new DeRiveanException("Cannot create window handle. Da fucQ!?");
    }
    glfwSetInputMode(windowHandle, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    glfwSetWindowPos(windowHandle, (GLFWvidmode.width(videModeBuffer) - getWidth()) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(videModeBuffer) - getHeight()) / 2);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowHandle);
    glfwSwapInterval(GL_FALSE);
    glfwSetInputMode(windowHandle, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    glfwSetCursorPos(windowHandle, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();
```

[image: wrong object order]

**EDIT**
Ok, now I know, that I have depth 24bit buffer, so bug is in other place :( ....

**Partially GOTCHA**
...I have reaped engine to smallest possible pieces and found, that everything is OK until I connect camera. Its strange, but if I can walk and look around, z-buffer will die; if I set static view, z-buffer happily live until it's end....

Comment: Check whether your video mode includes a depth buffer. `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS,32);`

Comment: This is default option, I've tried glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS,24); and glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS,32); both before glfwCreateWindow() and both with same result (as in image).... is there option, that checks if I have depth buffer available?

Comment: If you are using OpenGL 3.0 or older, or a compatibility profile, you can query the value of `GL_DEPTH_BITS` from OpenGL after you create your context. _That was removed in newer versions._ Also, 32-bit depth buffers are best left for FBOs, some platforms do not support them on the default framebuffer.